# HOW TO SOLVE There is no row at position 2 VB.NET using sqldatabase

Tags: vb.net-2010

1. Private Sub Charges()

   ```
     Dim Query As String
               Query = "Select * from Charges where DOctype='" & comboBoxTranType.Text & "'"
               Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(Query, con)
               con.Open()
               Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(Query, con)
               Dim dt As New DataTable
               dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
               dataAdapter.Dispose()
       If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                 LabelV001.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Head").ToString()
                   LabelV002.Text = dt.Rows(1).Item("Head").ToString()
                   LabelV003.Text = dt.Rows(2).Item("Head").ToString()
               End If


    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                       LabelFIELD1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Equation").ToString()
                       LabelFIELD2.Text = dt.Rows(1).Item("Equation").ToString()
                       LabelFIELD3.Text = dt.Rows(2).Item("Equation").ToString()

                   End If

                   con.Close()



               End Sub
   ```

   SIR WITH YOUR HELP I GOT THE RESULT BEFORE, BUT CAUSE OF ERROR FOR FIELDTEXT3 i.e There is no row at position 2, equation 3 cannot be calculated, pls help me out,

Comment: Please properly format your code and specify what you are asking, so we can understand your problem and help you to solve the same

Comment: I have Equation in my Database in Text format for Example: V001 * V002/100 V001 IS MY TEXTCHARGES1.TEXT AND V002 IS MY TEXTCHARGES2.TEXT, I WANT VALUE OF THE EQUATION IN TEXTCHARGES2.TEXT

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why they were so quick to close your new question...I was building an answer for it.

1. Click on Project --> Add Reference
2. Switch to the COM option
3. Select the "Microsoft Script Control 1.0" entry and click OK.

Now you can use code like below, creating code for textCharges1 --> V001 through textCharges25 --> V025:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private SC As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SC.Language = "VBScript"

        Dim ctl As Control
        Dim ctlName, functionBody As String
        functionBody = "Function {0}()" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "{0} = CDbl({1}.Text)" & vbCrLf & "End Function"
        For i As Integer = 1 To 25
            ctlName = "textCharges" & i
            ctl = Me.Controls.Find(ctlName, True).FirstOrDefault
            If Not IsNothing(ctl) Then
                SC.AddObject(ctlName, ctl, True)
                SC.AddCode(String.Format(functionBody, "V" & i.ToString("000"), ctlName))
            End If
        Next

        LABELFIELD2.Text = "V001*V002/100"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim result = SC.Eval(LABELFIELD2.Text)
            lblResult.Text = result
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblResult.Text = "{Error}"
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Running example:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have a series of TextBoxes that you want to add as V001, V002, etc...that could easily be done with a loop instead of hard coding each one separately.

Comment: Thanks Sir, There will be No of Text boxes and it will be AS FROM V001 TO .....V025

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR, I GOT THE ANSWER, AS YOU ASKED IF THERE ARE SERIES OF TEXTBOXES , YES THERE ARE, KINDLY TELL ME HOW TO DO FOR NO OF TEXTBOXES, AND ONCE AGAIN THANKS SIR

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Expected end of statement Shows Error at Line 13 before  End if

Comment: It works without error for me.  Show me your version of the code.